# How to retrieve only words using regex

Tags: regex, scala

Using regex expression, how can I retrieve only words, while ignoring any other symbols like commas, numbers, etc.?

```
val words = text.split("\b([-A-Za-z])+\b")
```

For example:

```
This is a nice day, my name is...
```

I want to get:

```
This, is, a, nice, day, my, name, is
```

while ignoring `,` and `...`.

Comment: In javascript I would use `str.split(/[ ,\?\.\d]/).filter(Boolean);` I use the filter because you may get empty strings in your array.

Comment: @enxaneta I use Scala as the tag of a post indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract all words including hyphenated words, you may use

```
"""\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)*\b""".r.findAllIn(s)
```

To support all Unicode letters, use `\p{L}` instead of the `[a-zA-Z]` character class:

```
val s = "This is a nice day, my name is..."
val res = """\b\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*\b""".r.findAllIn(s)
println(res.toList)
// => List(This, is, a, nice, day, my, name, is)
```

See the [Scala demo](http://rextester.com/CPRW39562).

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on non-letter:

```
val words = text.split("[^-A-Za-z]+")
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the symbol `+` means?

Comment: @ScalaBoy: It means 1 or more occurrence of preceding character. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/372239 and https://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

```
val p ="""[[a-z][A-Z]]+""".r
```

**In REPL:**

```
scala> val text = "This is a nice day, my name is..."
text: String = This is a nice day, my name is...

scala> p.findAllIn(text).toArray
res24: Array[String] = Array(This, is, a, nice, day, my, name, is)

scala> val text = "This is a nice_day, my_name is..."
text: String = This is a nice_day, my_name is...

scala> p.findAllIn(text).toArray
res26: Array[String] = Array(This, is, a, nice, day, my, name, is)
```

Comment: Only one pair of `[]` needed: `"[a-zA-Z]+".r`